# Convert a number to HH:MM:SS

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have a number `154958`. I want to convert to `HH:MM:SS`.

Answer I am looking is `15:49:58`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would treat this as formating output:

```
formatC(as.integer("154958"), 
        big.mark = ":", big.interval = 2L)
#[1] "15:49:58"
```

Answer (score 8):

Convert to date then substring:

```
substr(strptime("154958", format = "%H%M%S"), 12, 20)
```

Or even better version (thanks @Roland):

```
format(strptime("154958", format = "%H%M%S"), format = "%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: `format(strptime("154958",format="%H%M%S"), format="%H:%M:%S")` would be better.

Answer (score 5):

You may try the below.

```
> x <- "154958"
> gsub("^(\\d{2})(\\d{2})(\\d{2})$", "\\1:\\2:\\3", x)
[1] "15:49:58"
>
```

OR

```
> gsub("(\\d{2})(?!$)", "\\1:", x, perl=T)
[1] "15:49:58"
```

Comment: I think just `gsub("(..)(..)(..)", "\\1:\\2:\\3", x)` will be enough for the first option.

Comment: You just removed `perl=TRUE`, but I meant that you can simplify it even further with just using `(..)`. I also saw your massive downvotes were reversed. Cheers.

Comment: yep, i hope his anger is gone. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `chron` package

```
library(chron)
times(chron(times = "154958", format = "hms"))
## [1] 15:49:58
```

Answer (score 2):

or even more simply (as it is a timestamp, the number of character is known)

```
paste(substr(x,1,2),substr(x,3,4),substr(x,5,6),sep=":")
```

Comment: Or `paste(strsplit(x, '(?<=\\d{2})(?=\\d{2})', perl=TRUE)[[1]], collapse=":")`

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a derivative of the above answers but you can use the "hms" package:

```
library(hms)

strptime("154958", "%H%M%S") %>% hms::as.hms()
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to make a real date from it, try the following.

```
strptime("154958", "%H%M%S")
```

Defaults to the current day, so if today is the 24th of March 2015, you'll get:

> [1] "2015-03-24 15:49:58 CET"